# Replace Data and Read Write in Text File

Tags: python, text, read-write

I wanna make the editing processes to the input text file and rewrite the result as "new text file".
In my case, I have and "input.txt" and "template.txt" as of the following. I wanna rewrite "template.txt" depending on "input.txt" data by "python".

1. I wanna skip the lines starting with # in "template.txt"
2. Relace "BKUP" with the data in "input.txt"
   Could you please help me?

**input.txt**

ACTUAL

IN USE

NOT TESTING

**template.txt**

#It is the template.

This is BKUP.

#Thanks

**template.txt (Rewrite : Expected Output)**

This is ACTUAL.

This is IN USE.

This is NOT TESTING.

Comment: you wanna duplicate the `This is BKUP` line the number of input times or wanna replece just with the first input?

Comment: @marick Thanks for your help. 
I just wanna replace with all input lines without user interaction. If there is three input lines, template line will also be 3 lines and will replace at the place of "BKUP" and remove or skip the line starting with "#"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 files:

input.txt

```
ACTUAL

IN USE

NOT TESTING
```

template.txt

```
#It is the template.

This is BKUP.

#Thanks
```

main.py

```
#read the lines of the template file
with open("template.txt", "r") as file:
    template_lines = file.readlines()

#read the inputs
with open("input.txt", "r") as file:
    inputs = list(set(filter(lambda x:x!='', map(lambda x:x.rstrip().strip(), file.readlines()))))

# the line of the input chosen
chosen_input_index = 1

def print_inputs(inputs_list):
    for i, input_ in enumerate(inputs_list):
        print(f"{i}) {input_}")

# open and write the template file
with open("template.txt", "w") as file:
    # join the template lines in a text variable
    txt_template = "".join(template_lines)
    for i,line in enumerate(template_lines):
        if "BKUP" in line:
            print(f"Editing line num: {i}")
            print_inputs(inputs)
            # wait for an input from the user for the input line index
            inp = -1
            while inp not in range(len(inputs)):
                inp = input(">>> ")
                try: inp = int(inp)
                except: inp = -1

            # replace the next BKUP with the chosen input
            txt_template = txt_template.replace("BKUP", inputs[inp])
    # write back the edited template in the template.txt file
    file.write(txt_template)
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT:
intro text is for the "to edit line"

```
intro_text = "This is "
# open and write the template file
with open("template.txt", "w") as file:
    inputs_edited = "\n".join([intro_text+input_+"." for input_ in inputs])+ "\n"
    template_lines = list(map(lambda x: inputs_edited if "BKUP" in x else x, template_lines))
    file.write(''.join(template_lines))
```

if u wanna remove the lines with `#` do this when opening the template:

```
with open("template.txt", "r") as file:
    template_lines = list(filter(lambda x: "#" not in x, file.readlines()))
```

if u wanna put the same input more times remove the `list(set(` from the "read input"